# Webpack 4 extract css from scss not removing the sass file from complied file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, sass

I have gone through a lot of questions on stackoverflow and article before writing this question here.
I am successfully able to create the CSS file sass using webpack4.

I have file as below client.js, it import the scss

```
import React , { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './jobcard.scss';
```

here is my webpack config.

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    client: './src/client.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'asset'),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        { 
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader"
       },
       {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            "css-loader",
            "sass-loader"
          ]
       },
    ]
 },
 plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'main.css',
  })
]

}
```

It successfully creating the main.css and store in the '/asset' folder.
but the problem is when I complied client.js using babel. it has below the line.

```
require("./jobcard.scss");
```

its breaks due to the above line because in dist folder there is no such scss file as it's extract and placed in 'asset' folder. I want my css/image in 'asset' folder.

my expectation is my final css moved to '/asset' folder which is happening right now and the above line should get removed from complied client.js file. 
So I can refer the main.css on my index.html from asset location.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this [config](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js) to see if it work for you

```
module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Tony, it doesn't work, I tried... the same issue still exists